# Optimize MySQL query (generating stats)

Tags: mysql, optimization

DB tables:

[image]

[image]

I have got MySQL query :

```
select  calendar.datefield AS date, 
      ( SELECT  IFNULL(SUM(visits),0)
            FROM  link_stats
            WHERE  link_stats.link_id = '1'
              AND  statDate = date
      ) AS visits, 
      ( SELECT  Round(IFNULL(SUM(leads * (rate/1000)),0),3)
            FROM  link_stats
            WHERE  link_stats.link_id = '1'
              AND  statDate = date
      ) AS cash, 
      ( SELECT  IFNULL(SUM(leads),0)
            FROM  link_stats
            WHERE  link_stats.link_id = '1'
              AND  statDate = date
      ) AS leads
    from  `calendar`
    where  `calendar`.`datefield` between '2016-05-10' AND '2016-05-11'
```

I try generate stats report per link with blank days.

Example:

Between 11-01-2016 to 20-01-2016 and link doesn't has records with date 12-01-2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a table with all possible dates.  Call it TableOfDates and have one column: datefield

Then rearrange the query something like this:

```
select  d.datefield AS date,
        ls.visits, ls.cash, ls.leads
    from  TableOfDates d
    LEFT JOIN  `calendar` AS c  ON c.datefield = d.datefield
    LEFT JOIN  
      ( SELECT  statDate,
                IFNULL(SUM(visits),0) AS visits,
                Round(IFNULL(SUM(leads * (rate/1000)), 0),3) AS cash,
                IFNULL(SUM(leads),0) AS leads
            FROM  link_stats
            WHERE    ls.link_id = 1
              AND    statDate between '2016-01-11' AND '2016-01-20'
            GROUP BY statDate 
      ) AS ls  ON ls.statDate = d.datefield
    where  d.datefield        between '2016-01-11' AND '2016-01-20'
```